# How to apply 4-5(all) coupons together in Cart/checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I apply all coupons codes automatically in the checkout page?

```
function apply_coupon_product() {
    $coupon_code = $coupon->get_code();
if ( WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) {
        return;
    }
    WC()->cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
}

if user have 1 coupon then it will apply 1 if user have more than 1 coupons then apply all coupons in the cart/checkout page. any help please?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230388/creating-a-list-of-available-woocommerce-coupon-codes-and-display-anywhere-using  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979138/how-woocommerce-coupons-are-stored-in-database/42997287#42997287

Comment: @MartinMirchev is it possible to get coupon code which is allotted to customer email id ??

Comment: u can get it but wont apply since other events will check if you can assign coupon to an unallowed email.