# How to get more information from the coupon code list WooCommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce, coupon

I am using the code to display the coupon codes that are currently published in the shortcode from *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230388/creating-a-list-of-available-woocommerce-coupon-codes-and-display-anywhere-using)*.

The code displays a list of published coupon codes on the site.

How to get more? For example:

1. Coupon expiry date
2. Coupon amount
3. Description

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
add_shortcode('ac', 'coupon_list' );
function coupon_list() {
    $coupon_posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'order'            => 'asc',
        'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
    ) );

    $coupon_codes = []; // Initializing

    foreach( $coupon_posts as $coupon_post) {
        $coupon_codes[] = $coupon_post->post_name;
    }

    // Display available coupon codes
    return implode(', ', $coupon_codes) ; // always use return in a shortcode
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sYUy.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you are storing expirydate, amount as custom fields (say coupon_expirydate, coupon_amount) then,

```
add_shortcode('ac', 'coupon_list' );
function coupon_list() {
  $coupon_posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'name',
    'order'            => 'asc',
    'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
  ) );

  $coupon_codes = []; // Initializing

  foreach( $coupon_posts as $coupon_post) {
    setup_postdata( $coupon_post )
    $coupon_codes[] = [
        "coupon" => esc_html( get_the_title() ) //escaping html to display the title safely
        "coupon_expirydate" => get_field( "coupon_expirydate" ),
        "coupon_amount" => get_field( "coupon_amount" ),
        "description" => get_the_content()
    ];

  }

$coupon_codes= json_decode(json_encode($coupon_codes)); //converting to object for easy looping
  // Display available coupon codes
$coupontext="<table>
             <tr>
               <th>Sno</th>
               <th>Coupon</th>
               <th>Expiry date</th>
               <th>Amount</th>
               <th>Description</th>
             </tr>";
  foreach($coupon_codes as $k=>$coupon){
    $coupontext.= "<tr>
                     <td>".$k+1."</td>
                     <td>$coupon->coupon</td>
                     <td>$coupon->coupon_expirydate</td>
                     <td>$coupon->coupon_amount</td>
                     <td>$coupon->description</td>
                   </tr>";
  }

  $coupontext.="</table>";
  return $coupontext;
}
```

You you want to show only non-expired coupons just use meta query variable inside arguments of get_posts().

```
$coupon_posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'name',
    'order'            => 'asc',
    'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
                       array(
                         'key'   => 'coupon_expirydate',
                         'value' => date("Y-m-d"), // Set todays date
                         'compare' => '>=', // Return the ones greater than todays date
                         'type' => 'DATE'
                            )
                        )
  ) );
```